# Uploading files to facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a file to a Facebook Group using a script ( either using graph API or any other mechanism ). The FB says we can not use the Graph API to submit files to a FB group. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/files/

I am wondering have anyone tried this one before ? and is there a way to do this avoiding Graph API ?

I am sorry for my naiveness due to being a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to let your app create a mail and sent it to the FB group mailbox with attachment. However, it requires that someone accepts the file in the posts on the group.

I'm also in need for my app to upload files to my group (.txt files, however this seems to be only way as Graph-API don't support updating otherwise, unless it is images.